# How to prevent Prettier from removing semicolon and white spaces in { }

Tags: eslint, prettier

I have a javascript project formatted with Prettier and eslint. The issue is that when I save a code like this:

`` require('dotenv').config({ path: `${ PATH_CFG }/.env` }); process.env.APP_DATABASE = process.env.APP_DATABASE.replace('CREDENTIALS',  process.env.CONSUMER_USER); ``

I get this: the white space in `{ PATCH_CFG }` is removed, the semi-colon is removed, and the breaks with some moving to a new line. I also get an indentation in one of the lines:

`` require('dotenv').config({ path: `${PATH_CFG}/.env` }) process.env.APP_DATABASE = process.env.APP_DATABASE.replace( 'CREDENTIALS', process.env.COORDINATOR_USER ) ``

Any idea how I can fix this and maintain the original code using prettier & eslint?

Answer (score 0):

you could place the code in a disable block:

```
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
require('dotenv').config({ path: `${ PATH_CFG }/.env` }); process.env.APP_DATABASE = process.env.APP_DATABASE.replace('CREDENTIALS',  process.env.CONSUMER_USER);
/* eslint-enable prettier/prettier */
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.